# Flutter Reloading List with Streams & RxDart

Tags: dart, flutter, reactive-programming

I have one question regarding how to reload a list after refresh indicator is called in Flutter, using Streams and RxDart.

Here is what I have , my model class:

```
    class HomeState {

      List<Event> result;
      final bool hasError;
      final bool isLoading;

       HomeState({
        this.result,
        this.hasError = false,
        this.isLoading = false,
      });

      factory HomeState.initial() =>
          new HomeState(result: new List<Event>());
      factory HomeState.loading() => new HomeState(isLoading: true);
      factory HomeState.error() => new HomeState(hasError: true);

    }


    class HomeBloc {

      Stream<HomeState> state;
      final EventRepository repository;

      HomeBloc(this.repository) { 
        state = new Observable.just(new HomeState.initial());
      }

      void loadEvents(){
        state = new Observable.fromFuture(repository.getEventList(1)).map<HomeState>((List<Event> list){
          return new HomeState(
              result: list,
              isLoading: false 
          );    
        }).onErrorReturn(new HomeState.error())
        .startWith(new HomeState.loading());
      }

    }
```

My widget:

```
    class HomePageRx extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _HomePageRxState createState() => _HomePageRxState();
    }

    class _HomePageRxState extends State<HomePageRx> {
      HomeBloc bloc;

      _HomePageRxState() {
        bloc = new HomeBloc(new EventRest());
        bloc.loadEvents();
      }

      Future<Null> _onRefresh() async {
        bloc.loadEvents();
        return null;
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new StreamBuilder(
            stream: bloc.state,
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<HomeState> snapshot) {
              var state = snapshot.data;
              return new Scaffold(
                body: new RefreshIndicator(
                  onRefresh: _onRefresh,
                  child: new LayoutBuilder(builder:
                      (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints boxConstraints) {
                    if (state.isLoading) {
                      return new Center(
                        child: new CircularProgressIndicator(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
                          strokeWidth: 5.0,
                        ),
                      );
                    } else {
                      if (state.result.length > 0) {
                        return new ListView.builder(
                            itemCount: snapshot.data.result.length,
                            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                              return new Text(snapshot.data.result[index].title);
                            });
                      } else {
                        return new Center(
                          child: new Text("Empty data"),
                        );
                      }
                    }
                  }),
                ),
              );
            });
      }
    }
```

The problem is when I do the pull refresh from list, the UI doesn't refresh (the server is called, the animation of the refreshindicator also), I know that the issue is related to the stream but I don't know how to solve it.

Expected result : Display the CircularProgressIndicator until the data is loaded

Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not supposed to change the instance of `state`.

You should instead submit a new value to the observable. So that `StreamBuilder`, which is listening to `state` will be notified of a new value.

Which means you can't just have an `Observable` instance internally, as `Observable` doesn't have any method for adding pushing new values. So you'll need a `Subject`.

Basically this changes your Bloc to the following :

```
class HomeBloc {
  final Stream<HomeState> state;
  final EventRepository repository;
  final Subject<HomeState> _stateSubject;

  factory HomeBloc(EventRepository respository) {
    final subject = new BehaviorSubject(seedValue: new HomeState.initial());
    return new HomeBloc._(
        repository: respository,
        stateSubject: subject,
        state: subject.asBroadcastStream());
  }

  HomeBloc._({this.state, Subject<HomeState> stateSubject, this.repository})
      : _stateSubject = stateSubject;

  Future<void> loadEvents() async {
    _stateSubject.add(new HomeState.loading());

    try {
      final list = await repository.getEventList(1);
      _stateSubject.add(new HomeState(result: list, isLoading: false));
    } catch (err) {
      _stateSubject.addError(err);
    }
  }
}
```

Also, notice how `loadEvent` use `addError` with the exception. Instead of pushing a `HomeState` with a `hasError: true`.

Comment: Awesome man, thank you, I need to learn about Reactive programming.

Comment: You may want to add a factory constructor so that you can pass `state` as final

Comment: @diegoveloper I edited my example to include a factory constructor

Comment: Thanks, Do you have any reference/page about these concepts  Subjects/Observable/Stream/Sink/ etc... ?

Comment: [You can use the documentation of ReactiveX](http://reactivex.io/documentation). In the end rxdart is just a dart implementation of rx. As for Sink/Stream themselves, well if you understand Observables you should understand Stream/Sink